# Extjs5 displayfield with html-value don't work auto height

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

After update extjs4->extjs5 `displayfield` don't resize height to html content. only resize for text content.
how to fix?

ps: and i can't get properly height of diplayfield html-content.

pps: html-content created by `htmleditor`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue while porting an extjs4 application to extjs5.

[I employed this hack as a temporary fix](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/au9):

I added a `renderer` to the `displayfield` and created html that is similar to the original elements generated in extjs4.  Then i apply an `update` to the `displayfield` `afterrender` to display this html instead of the original output.

```
            {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Testing',
                value: 'Hello <br/> Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>Hello <br/>',
                renderer: function(value, x) {
                    //hack for displayfield issue in ExtJS 5
                    var rtn = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "</br>");
                    var html = [
                        '<tbody>',
                            '<tr class="x-form-item-input-row">',
                                '<td style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="' + x.labelWidth + '" class="x-field-label-cell">',
                                    '<label class="x-form-item-label x-unselectable x-form-item-label-left" style="width:' + x.labelWidth + 'px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on">' + x.getFieldLabel() +':</label>',
                                '</td>',
                                '<td class="x-form-item-body x-form-display-field-body " colspan="2">',
                                    '<div class="x-form-display-field" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="">',
                                        rtn,
                                    '</div>',
                                '</td>',
                            '</tr>',
                        '</tbody>'
                    ];
                    x.on('afterrender',function(){
                         x.update(html.join(''));
                    });
                    return '';
                },

            }
```